# checkbox не сбрасывается при нажатии кнопки отмена

Tags: javascript, jquery

прошу помочь. Допустим, есть модальное окно для поиска чего-либо, в котором можно что-то выбрать (id, name и тд), пользователь нажимает на checkbox айдишника или имени, но потом передумал что-то искать и нажал отмену. Как сделать так, чтобы checkbox сбрасывался (не запоминался?)?

```
change: function(func)
{
    var input = func.find("input").eq(0);
    var checked = input.prop('checked');
    console.log("checkbox");
    if(checked)
    {
        func.removeClass('checked');
        jQuery('checked').attr( 'autocomplete', 'off' );
    }
    else
    {
        func.addClass('checked');
    }
    input.prop('checked', !checked);
    input = null;
},
```

пробовал jQuery('checked').attr( 'autocomplete', 'off' ); чтобы нажатие сбрасывалось, но не работает, чекбокс все равно остается нажатым при отмене

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну есть несколько вариантов сброса значений чекбоксов и так далее

1. Сброс всей формы. Просто внутри тега формы добавьте `input` с типом `reset` и всё все чекбоксы будут сами сбрасываться (без js кода!)
2. Второй способ если чекбокс не в форме или надо сбрасывать только его, то можно просто присвоить `elem.checked = false` как в примере ниже (код js)

```js
var resetBtn = document.querySelector('.reset2');

resetBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var checkBox = document.querySelector('input[name="myCheck2"]');
  checkBox.checked = false;
});
```

```html
<form>
  <label>
    Значение в форме
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck" value="1" />
  </label>

  <input class="reset" type="reset" value="reset form"/>
</form>

<label>
    Значение 2
    <input type="checkbox" name="myCheck2" value="1" />
  </label>
  
    <input class="reset2" type="button" value="reset"/>
```